# Haproxy + TCP + SSL Passthrough + send-proxy

Tags: ssh, tcp, proxy, haproxy

I am using the following Haproxy configuration to pass SSH connections to the backend servers.

```
global
log 127.0.0.1 local0
daemon
maxconn 2048 

defaults
log global
timeout connect 500000ms
timeout client 86400s
timeout server 86400s

listen stats
    bind :1936
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /

frontend front-ssh-servers
mode tcp
option tcplog
bind *:22
default_backend back-ssh-servers
timeout client 8h

backend back-ssh-servers
mode tcp
balance leastconn
stick-table type ip size 1m expire 8h
stick on src
server server1 X.X.X.X:22 check send-proxy
server server2 X.X.X.X:22 check send-proxy
server server3 X.X.X.X:22 backup send-proxy
```

The idea of adding send-proxy was to capture the actual client IP in the backend SSH servers. However, with send-proxy or send-proxy-v2, the connections are not reaching the destination backend SSH servers. Without the send-proxy option, the connections are reaching the backend SSH servers.

The Haproxy version is 1.8. Haproxy logs show the below.

```
2023-02-09T10:27:59-08:00 127.0.0.1 haproxy[3190902]: X.X.X.X:36730 [09/Feb/2023:10:27:59.175] front-ssh-servers back-ssh-servers/X.X.X.X 1/0/8 21 SD 2/1/0/0/0 0/0
```

The termination code is "SD". I read that proxy protocol also needs to be enabled at the backend hosts. Appreciate any help on how to achieve this for SSH connections. My backend hosts are running OpenSSH_7.4p1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see real IPs of SSH client of SSH servers running behind AWS ELB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652016/how-to-see-real-ips-of-ssh-client-of-ssh-servers-running-behind-aws-elb)

Comment: Thanks Steffen. Looks like a relatively complex setup. I will still look forward for alternatives of mmproxy.

Comment: OpenSSH does not support the proxy protocol, so you somehow need to make sure it actually gets a TCP connection with the real source IP address.